# How can I access my models in sailsjs outside a controller?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a controller that looks like this.

```
module.exports = {

    readbyslug: function (req, res) {
    var slug = req.param('id');
    Store.findOneByName(slug.split('-').join(' '))
      .then(function(err, store){
      if(err)
        res.send({status:'error', msg:'no store'});
      res.send(store);

    });
  }
};
```

however, I would rather not have all this login in the controllers, I would rather stick them in another module.

My question is, how do I access the models? are they global or something?

Comment: Have you tried `var store = require(/path/to/models/store)`?

Comment: @pdoherty926 also a perfectly valid approach!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Chadams-- models are global by default.  So if you did `sails generate model foo`, you could access `Foo` in your code.  If you'd rather not access them that way, you can use the `sails` reference to access `sails.models.foo`, which is the same thing.

Hope that helps!

> btw this auto-globalization is disable-able by customizing  [`sails.config.globals`](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-globals).  For example:

```
// To configure what's available globally, make a new file, `config/globals.js`
// with the following contents:

// In this example, I'll disable globalization of models, as well as _ and async.
// (But I'll leave the `sails` global available.)

// Variables which will be made globally accessible to the server process
module.exports.globals = {
  _ : false,
  async: false,
  models: false,
  sails: true
};
```

Comment: ```module.exports = {
    readbyslug: function (req, res) {... if you try to use Store or  sails.models.store OUTSIDE module.exports or outside function (req, res) you will get the undefined

Comment: I've created custom directory `app/api/migrations` for migrations and I cannot access it. `sails not defined`