# How to access models outside controllers in Sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, sails.js

I am using Sails v11.

I have a model each for a tenant(its a multi-tenant app) which is picked for action based on logic inside the controller to determine the tenant, I am trying to create a hashmap of "tenantID"/"model" pairs to achive this. I am able to do this inside the controller, however as I don't want to create a hashMap for every action, I am trying to build this map inside a config file and I intend to export it to be used in the controller.

But I am not able to access the models outside controller to create this hashmap.

I found a discussion on this at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617716/how-can-i-access-my-models-in-sailsjs-outside-a-controller) link.

However, the suggested method is not working.

```
var map = new Map();
map.set('item1', Foo)
module.exports.modelMap = {
    productMap: map;
  }
```

I am receiving these syntax errors.

```
map.set('item1', Foo)           --> ReferenceError: Foo is not defined
map.set('item1', sails.models.Foo)  --> ReferenceError: sails is not defined
map.set('item1', sails.models['Foo'])   --> ReferenceError: sails is not defined
```

Making model names lower case, yields the same errors.

```
firstuser@ubuntu:~/project-dir$ npm --version sails
2.14.7
firstuser@ubuntu:~/project-dir$ sails --version
0.11.2
firstuser@ubuntu:~/project-dir$
```

Could you please suggest the correct way to access models outside controllers for version 0.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sails' models are global by default. TO access Foo in your code (outside of controllers) you can use the [sails global variable](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/globals). You can change this behaviour in config/globals.js file.

```
sails.models.model
```

In case of Foo:

```
sails.models.foo; //note the lowercase
```

Comment: Thanks Miguel for the answer.

Comment: not working. undefined for any of names (Model, sails.models.Model, sails.models.model)

Comment: sorry undefined for (Model, sails.models.Model) and not function `find` for sails.models.model.find()